# Populate array up to a certain number of values

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I wonder if this is possible.
There is an object like this:

> data.json:

```
[
 {"DATE":"September","VALUE":[5,17,8,9]}
]
```

As you can see, the array "VALUE" consists of 4 numbers at the moment. (This may vary). However, I would like it to contain always - let's say 10 - numbers.

Therefore the array should be populated with zeroes.

The result should look like this:

> data.json:

```
[
 {"DATE":"September","VALUE":[5,17,8,9,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
]
```

Of course, the initial array could already contain the expected count of ten values. Then, nothing should be changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following could easily be modified to truncate the array if it is initially too long, if that is required:

```
def expand(n; value): . + [range(length;n) | value];

map(.VALUE |= expand(10;0))
```

### One-liner

```
jq 'map(.VALUE|=.+[range(length;10)|0])' data.json | sponge data.json
```